# Generar getters and setters en ECLIPSE

Tags: java

resulta que tengo que trabajar con este IDE por fuerza mayor y llevo un rato intentando solucionar este error, seguro que es una tonteria pero en net beans nunca tube problemas al respecto, gracias de antemano

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 4):

El problema es que la clase `Empleados` no tiene ningún atributo, por eso no se pueden generar los métodos getters y setters. Me parece que lo que quieres es delarar los atributos Nombre, Edad, Salario, etc, pero lo que hiciste fue declarar variables dentro del constructor de la clase. La forma correcta de declarar los atributos en una clase es esta:

```
public class Empleados {
    private String nombre;
    private int edad;
    private int salario;
    ...

    public Empleados() {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Los tres puntos (...) indican que puedes tener código adicional donde estos están.